# Magento 2 : Need to import product image from external url

Tags: magento2, import, product-images, importexport

I just need to import all product images from external url , can i able to do this using default functionality in magento 2.

If yes, how can i use this product images external url during import csv file in magento ?
is there any setting , please share your if anyone have idea

Comment: same problem, I put the http address of the google logo, in base_image and tumbnail_image, and small_image, and I have the following error : Imported resource (image) could not be downloaded from external resource due to timeout or access permissions

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/162637)

Answer (score 2):

OOTB Magento provides this feature so you don't need to do anything for this. For this, You can just pass your Image URL (`base_image`, `small_image`, `thumbnail_image`, or `additional_images`)

http://example.com/images/image.jpg

Source(Method 2): [DevDocs](http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/system/data-import-product-images.html)

Comment: i getting below error while entering external url :  Imported resource (image) could not be downloaded from external resource due to timeout or access permissions in row(s): 1

Comment: please check the image is accessible or not or try to assign first sample image  like google logo https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png

Comment: Yes Its accessible using execute direct file url.

Comment: Is it need to add any path into 
Images File Directory field while import csv

Comment: no, you don't need images file directory. or please try the image with another domain (some sample image to just confirm if domain problem or not)

Comment: @KeyurShah Have you idea how to save external images URL to pub/media/catalog/category/ directory for category image import via csv.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/279578/magento-2-import-categories-images-external-url-via-csv 

your help would be appropriated.

Comment: @Camit1dk How was your problem solved?

Comment: @AnonymousRecord not remember what i have done for that but its working fine with latest magento version using third party image url. You can try with another image url just for test so you can make sure about its not issue related to permission.

Comment: anyone manage to solve this?