# Magento 2: Import categories images external url via csv

Tags: csv, magento2.3.1, external-images

I have import categories via CSV and I would like to import category image from external URL. I have used Magento ver. 2.3.1

I have tried to save images to the category but can't able to get success.

If any have idea how to import category image from external URL then let me know.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code. I hope it will help you.

```
use \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
include('../app/bootstrap.php');
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$url = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager = $url->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$mediaurl= $storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
$state = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');   

$websiteId = $storeManager->getWebsite()->getWebsiteId();
$storeId = $store->getStoreId();
$rootNodeId = $store->getRootCategoryId();
$rootCat = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category');

$cat_info = $rootCat->load($rootNodeId);
$categorys=array('Living','Sofa','Tables','Beds');// Category Names
foreach($categorys as $cat){
    $name=ucfirst($cat);

    $url=strtolower($cat);

    $cleanurl = trim(preg_replace('/ +/', ", preg_replace(‘/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/’, ", urldecode(html_entity_decode(strip_tags($url))))));

    $categoryFactory=$objectManager->get(‘\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory’);

    $categoryTmp = $categoryFactory->create();$categoryTmp->setName($name);
    $categoryTmp->setIsActive(true);$categoryTmp->setUrlKey($cleanurl);
    $categoryTmp->setData('description', 'description');
    $categoryTmp->setParentId($rootCat->getId());
    $mediaAttribute = array ('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail');
    $categoryTmp->setImage('/category.png', $mediaAttribute, true, false);// Path pub/meida/catalog/category/category.png
    $categoryTmp->setStoreId($storeId);
    $categoryTmp->setPath($rootCat->getPath());
    $categoryTmp->save();

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.
That way only save image name. But How can copy image from external URL to pub/media/catalog/category/ directory.

Comment: via zip we need to extract in location.

Comment: You are right that way already working. 
I have need to put external image path from CSV and import it to the category.

Comment: i suggest to buy extension for that.

Comment: @Kirti Nariya How did you solved your problem ?

Comment: @AnonymousRecord I was fixed issue to put full path of external image in csv.

Comment: Can you help me a little bit in inbox

Comment: @Kirti Nariya  Can you take a look at my CSV  :  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11BZveLDWgpWSsHUVAkconpc3uVPEqBDvPzvhmeIIs5M/edit?usp=sharing    what's wrong with It???

Comment: Image url looks fine. but try some external image from website.